# Different when encrypting using AES-128 bit on javascript

Tags: aes, cryptojs

I encrypt using AES-128 bits using the CBC method in PHP but when I try it in javascript they produce different outputs

I tried crypto-js on javascript by adapting my code on php

the php code what i made :

```
$secretKey = "someivtextforaes";
$ivKey = 'somesecretkeytxt';
$token = 'BD';
$cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($token, $cipher, $secretKey, false, $ivKey);
return $ciphertext_raw;
```

this output is :
rtFKwdZt4wzgRsgYG/LbiQ==

i try this method on javascript using crypto-js, this is the code :

```
let secretKey = "someivtextforaes";
let ivKey = 'somesecretkeytxt';
let token = 'BD';
let cipherData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(token, secretKey, { iv: ivKey });
console.log(cipherData.toString())
```

but they have a different output :
U2FsdGVkX1+QsOS9lM2F2Emq

i expect the same output for encryption, someone can figure out this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the PHP-code, code and output are inconsistent. The current code returns the output `50CqXivvXXTfw276AZ8IjA==` (the posted output is only obtained if key and IV are swapped).

In the JavaScript-code key and IV must be passed as `WordArray`, e.g.

```
let secretKey = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("...");
```

Currently the key is passed as string and therefore interpreted as passphrase, from which key and IV are generated (see *[The Cipher Input](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input)*).

Comment: You are right!! i need to passed first, thanks a lot for you